# How can I easily copy files from an Android device to a computer wirelessly via command line?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, file-transfer, file-management, command-line

I need to copy jpegs from an Android phone's sdcard to a computer, ideally through command line (/storage/sdcard1/*.jpg to a remote location)

I've tried Izzy's solution from [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30362/airdroid-modifies-timestamps-of-copied-files) like so:

```
scp -p -P 2222 root@192.168.1.19:/storage/sdcard1/*.jpg ~/Desktop/pull/
```

but got this error:

```
sh: scp: not found
```

The scp and ftp commands are missing on the device, so is there a way to get this working ?

I've also looked at busybox and had some success doing so:

```
cd /storage/sdcard1 && for jpg in *.jpg; do ftpput -u user -p pass 192.168.1.33 ./Desktop/pull/$jpg $jpg;done
```

Another thing that worked is [this ls solution](https://superuser.com/questions/291423/how-to-copy-a-file-without-using-scp-inside-an-ssh-session) but for single files and I'm not experienced enough with bash scripting for this to work on multiple files.

I'm looking for the simplest solution (with fewest install/setup steps).
What is the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: You might want to check [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside). It's a "little monster", providing a bunch of things you might not need, but amongst others, AFAIR, there was also scp included.

Comment: I've installed TerminalIDE and I get scp with that one too, unless I'm doing it wrong. However I've managed to create links to scp using [this article](http://adrianpopagh.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/android-adding-scpsftp-support-to.html)

Comment: I didn't try that part yet. As you've found a solution: Would you mind answering the question yourself, including at least an excerpt of the linked article / steps you've performed? Would be great!

Comment: If rooted, install adb wireless on the phone and then use adb commands to copy the files via push/pull

Comment: @BryanDenny sounds good. I see many ADB wireless apps on the play store. Which one did you have in mind ?Also, adb seems to only work with one device at a time. I will need to control many.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza the app I use no longer seems to be on the market: http://www.appbrain.com/app/siir.es.adbWireless ADB should be able to control many, you can tell it which device with the -s flag